# Returning an array from an activity

Tags: android, arraylist, tostring, object-to-string

I am currently working on an android project and I want to be able to startActivityForResult so that I can return an array of.

The array is an `ArrayList<Spanned>` lets say its called myArray.

From what I've read I can't return an array directly from the activty using the set result so I was thinking that once the array has added all the data to the array, I can then call the toString function on it, i.e. `myArray.toString()`.

If I do this, I have no idea how I can then convert this back into the original `ArrayList<Spanned>`.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

Use [setResult(int, Intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29). From the child activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("mydata", mydata);

setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

### Serialization

if the problem is about serialization you can use [Html.toHtml and Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html). With toHtml you conver the Spanned to string, and fromHtml you get the spanned back. In the   child activity serialize the Spanned and put in extra:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
ArrayList<Spanned> myData;
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Spanned item : myData)
    strings.add(Html.toHtml(item));
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("mydata", strings);

setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

to get back the data in the caller activity, use the intent passed in onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ArrayList<Strings> strings = data.getStringArrayListExtra("mydata");
    ArrayList<Spanned> spanned = new ArrayList<Spanned>();
    for(String s : strings)
       spanned.add(Html.fromHtml(s));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, how would I then get this ArrayList<Spanned> back out again so that I can process the data within in.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something but still not sure what you mean with Html.toHtml etc. I have an ArrayList<Spanned> which I am setting as, in your, example, myData and storing it in the intent to set the result. In the OnActivityResult function I then need to get out my data back to being an ArrayList<Spanned>

Comment: I added an example in the answer